# Express js session module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

```
var session = require('express-session');
```

When I try to connect this module, I get an error: 'Cannot find module 'express-session''. But I install this module: `npm install express-session`

Help me please.

Comment: Make sure express-session module is inside node_modules

Comment: It is located in the node_modules folder.